# Can't send large files with sockets

Tags: java, file, sockets, server

I am trying to make a Server Client structure thats sends files but I am having problems when I send large files with size more than 200 MB.
I send them using `ObjectOutputStream` with my own object that has the file in a byte array and where I want to save it using the Apache commons libary.

Client SendMethod

```
try{
        Socket s = new Socket(ip, serverPort);

        ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(ClientFilePath+"\\"+ClientFileName);

        datainBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(file);

        Packet paquete = new Packet(datainBytes,ServerFileDirectory,ClientFileName);

        output.writeObject(paquete);
        output.close();

    } catch (ConnectException e){
        //noinspection MagicConstant
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(contentPane,"Conexion perdida","ERROR",0);
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(contentPane,"No tienes permisos para movere este archivo","ERROR",0);
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Server ReceiveMethod

```
Packet paquete = null;

    try {

        //ClientIN is the input from the client initialized earlier
        paquete = (Packet) ClientIN.readObject();

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File(paquete.getFilePathDestiny()+"\\"+paquete.getFileName()), paquete.getData());
```

The exact problem that I have is the server is trying to read the file but hangs and it does nothing.

Comment: Can you post the `ClientIN.readObject()` method?

Comment: @FrancescoPitzalis ClientIn is the ObjectInputStream of the Client Socket

Comment: Oh ok, it seemed a custom static method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an Object/Stream is usually only a good idea if you are sending objects.  In this case you are sending a file which you can stream progressively to the server.  If you stream the data, it can be of any size e.g. >> 2 GB.

Rather than hanging I suspect it's just taking a very long time.  Object/Stream are versatile but not very fast for large amounts of data.

Comment: Im sending the object packet that consist in the array of the data and the directions where i want to save it, if u want i can upload the object.

Comment: @IsmaelBlasco most of your data is not an object but the contents of a file. It is better to send a file progressively as a Stream of bytes. This way the file of the file is not important.

Comment: so wath should i do to stream the data? since wath im actually doing sems to pass the memory limit

Comment: @IsmaelBlasco what you should do is to read a portion of the file at a time e.g. 32 KB, and write this to the socket progressively. On the receiving side you can read the data as you receive it and write it directly to the file.  This way you only need 32 KB of memory for any size file even multi-GB files. (You can reduce the buffer size if this is too much)  This will work with an ObjectStream, but later you should find a way to replace it to improve performance.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation i will try it